# How to print the number of times the program is executed?

Tags: c

I want to write a simple C program which would print the number of times that program itself got executed (by user).

for example,

output should be
`You are executing this program 3rd time`

I first thought of using file handling but later came to know about `volatile` and `register`.

Is there any use of `volatile` or `register` in this context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `volatile` and `register` are only meaningful within the same run. Instead, store a counter in a file.

Comment: Is there any way other than using the file?

Comment: @Heisenberg: You could also use shared memory.

Comment: @Heisenberg -- In Windows, you could use the registry, but that's almost the same thing as modifying a file (you'd be modifying the Windows registry file).  If you want the program to remember how many times it has been run even if the machine is shut off or re-booted, you have to store the count in a file somehow (or in some sort of non-volatile memory).

Comment: you could also write a daemon (or even a web service) with which you could register the programs you run, but the code would be more complex